# Why can I not use the MsBuild TaskLoggingHelper in a custom task constructor?

Tags: logging, msbuild

When the following code is run in MSBuild I get an InvalidOperationException. I was wondering why this is?

```
public class SimpleTask3 : Task
{
    public SimpleTask3()
    {
        Log.LogMessage(MessageImportance.High, "A MESSAGE");
    }


    public override bool Execute()
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

The full error received is as follows

```
error MSB4061: The "SimpleTask3" task could not be instantiated from ...ConsoleApplication1.dll
error MSB4061: System.InvalidOperationException: Task attempted to log before it was initialized. Message was: A MESSAGE
error MSB4061:    at Microsoft.Build.Shared.ErrorUtilities.ThrowInvalidOperation(String resourceName, Object[] args)
error MSB4061:    at Microsoft.Build.Utilities.TaskLoggingHelper.LogMessage(MessageImportance importance, String message, Object[] messageArgs)
error MSB4061:    at SimpleTask3.SimpleTask3..ctor() in SimpleTask.cs:line 10
error MSB4060: The "SimpleTask3" task hasbeen declared or used incorrectly, or failed during construction. Check the spelling of the task name and the assembly name.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TaskLoggingHelper instances log via BuildEngine.LogMessageEvent so they require that BuildEngine instance before they can be used. From the [source code](https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/blob/master/src/Shared/TaskLoggingHelper.cs#L335):

```
// If BuildEngine is null, task attempted to log before it was set on it,
// presumably in its constructor. This is not allowed, and all
// we can do is throw.
if (BuildEngine == null)
{
  ErrorUtilities.ThrowInvalidOperation("LoggingBeforeTaskInitialization", e.Message);
}
```

The BuildEngine property forwards to _taskInstance.BuildEngine and _taskInstance is the Task which created the TaskLoggingHelper. A Task (from which you derive directly) does this in it's constructor:

```
protected Task()
{
  _log = new TaskLoggingHelper(this);
}
```

so at that point _taskInstance.BuildEngine is still null; it has to get set elewhere. How and why is basically out of scope for this answer because it doesn't help you: you cannot log in the constructor and there isn't anything you can change about it..

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. Could you explain the how and why? I get that it doesn't help me but I was more asking out of interest. Thanks again.

Comment: I don't really now why it is done like that as it's not explpained in the code but one possible reason is so that the constructor is kept simple so you can just write your parameterless constructor without having to bother passing arguments to the base class constructor, and the rest of the code takes care of setting the BuildEngine without you having to care about it. Which is done here: https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/blob/master/src/Build/BackEnd/TaskExecutionHost/TaskExecutionHost.cs#L369